# 403 error in production from WindowsAzure.Storage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a WebForms app that uses the WindowsAzure.Storage API v3. It works fine in development and in one production environment, but I'm rolling out a new instance and any code that calls out Azure Blob Storage gives me a 403 error.

I've been fiddling with this for awhile, and it fails on any call out to Blob Storage, so rather than show my code I'll show my stack trace:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8525404
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) +1541

[StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) +2996
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) +177
   ObsidianData.Azure.Storage.GetContainer(CloudBlobClient client, Containers targetContainer) in D:\Dev\nSource\Obsidian\Source\ObsidianData\Azure\Storage.vb:84
   ObsidianWeb.Leads.HandleListenLink(String fileName, HyperLink link) in D:\Dev\nSource\Obsidian\Source\ObsidianWeb\Bdc\Leads.aspx.vb:188
   ObsidianWeb.Leads.LoadEntity_ContactDetails(BoLead lead) in D:\Dev\nSource\Obsidian\Source\ObsidianWeb\Bdc\Leads.aspx.vb:147
   ObsidianWeb.Leads.LoadEntity(BoLead Lead) in D:\Dev\nSource\Obsidian\Source\ObsidianWeb\Bdc\Leads.aspx.vb:62
   EntityPages.EntityPage`1.LoadEntity() +91
   EntityPages.EntityPage`1.Page_LoadComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +151
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4018
```

Here's what I've tried...

- The AzureStorageConnectionString that fails in this environment definitely works in production
- Other connection strings (from the other  production environment, which works) also get a 403 here
- There seemed to be an issue with timestamps in some old versions of the REST api (which I am not directly using...) so I made certain the times are correct, even tried switching the server to UTC time.
- Tried toggling the connection string between http/https.
- Upgraded to the latest version of the API (v3.1)
- Tried fiddling with the code to ensure that every call out to Azure Storage gets 403. It does.
- In desperation, Installed Azure Powershell on the server just to verify that some type of communication with Azure is working. And that worked fine.
- Browsed to the azure management portal as well and that works fine.

Any ideas? This should just be using port 80 or 443, right? So there should be no way this is some kind of network issue. Let me know if that's wrong.

- The working production machine is an Azure VM (Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5)
  There are also some differences with the server:
- This new machine is physical hardware (Server 2012 and IIS 8)
- This IS using a different storage account inside my azure subscription, however I've tried a total of 3 connection strings and none of them work here.

**UPDATE:** someone asked to see the code. Okay, I wrote a class called Azure.Storage, which just abstracts my cloud storage code. We are failing on a call  to Storage.Exists, so here's the part of that class that feels relevant:

```
    Public Shared Function Exists(container As Containers, blobName As String) As Boolean
        Dim Dir As CloudBlobContainer = GetContainer(container)
        Dim Blob As CloudBlockBlob = Dir.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName.ToLower())

        Return Blob.Exists()
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetContainer(client As CloudBlobClient, targetContainer As Containers)
        Dim Container As CloudBlobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(targetContainer.ToString.ToLower())
        Container.CreateIfNotExists()
        Container.SetPermissions(New BlobContainerPermissions() With {.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob})

        Return Container
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetCloudBlobClient() As CloudBlobClient
        Dim Account As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.Cloud.AzureStorageConnectionString())

        Return Account.CreateCloudBlobClient()
    End Function
```

...**Containers** is just an enum of container names (there are several):

```
 Public Enum Containers
     CallerWavs
     CampaignImports
     Delve
     Exports
     CampaignImages
     Logos
     ReportLogos
     WebLinkImages
 End Enum
```

...Yes, they have upper-case characters, which causes problems. Everything is forced to lowercase before it goes out.

Also I did verify that the correct AzureConnectionString is coming out of my settings class. Again, I tried a few that work elsewhere. And this one works elsewhere also!

Comment: I don't suppose you could post your code could you ?

Comment: Please check the clock on the servers in question. You can also get 403 error if the time on the server is not in sync (+/- 15 minutes deviation is allowed) with the time on storage servers.

Comment: @GauravMantri Checked that, that's in the list I included in the question, but thanks. ;)

Comment: Another thing you could try is take the InnerException which should be a WebException, read its response stream to see more details about the error.

Comment: @GauravMantri Hrmmm, I'll try that. Do you think that would provide more than what I got in the stack trace?

Comment: Yes. When you read the response stream of WebException, you get an XML back which contains more details about this 403 error. Something like this (in C#):             using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) webException.Response)
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

Comment: @GauravMantri Hmm. Okay, when I tried that I got a stream not available exception. But! From HttpWepResponse I found StatusDescription, and that said: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: @GauravMantri From what I'm seeing that does seem consistent with the timestamp issue... That seems like a dead end but I will dig into it again.

Comment: Hmmm...very weird error. I'm intrigued. This server where you're getting the error is not hosted in Azure. Right? Let me know what you find.

Comment: @GauravMantri That's right, this is physical hardware and I'm remoted into it. Stay tuned while I double check the time issue.

Comment: @GauravMantri ...It was off by 1 day Guarav. I have no idea how I stared right at that more than once and didn't see it. That must have been the third of fourth time I checked that. So frustrating, but thanks for the help, you got me there. Maybe make an answer and I'll accept it? :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please check the clock on the servers in question. Apart from the incorrect account key, you can also get 403 error if the time on the server is not in sync with the time on storage servers (Give or take +/- 15 minutes deviation is allowed).

Comment: That turned out to be it, I checked it at least twice. Maybe that's what I get for working at 2am. BTW, I've used your Cerebrata tech and I liked it, thanks for both :)

Comment: OMG, I was almost going nuts. This is so stupid. Why on earth should it return 403 for time difference, And why not at least providing a meaningful message like "Your request time can not be accepted".

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this error.  My problem was that I had turned ON dynamic IP security restrictions in my web.config and the number of files being downloaded in some cases (e.g. with pages with lots of images) was exceeding the max thresholds I had defined in my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Access key is not same as connection string using by the source code.

So try to recheck on your **Azure -> [Storage Account Name] -> Access Keys -> key1 -> Key & Connection string**.