# Windows Azure Queue returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: azure, message-queue

Using the following code (I've obfuscated the actual credentials):

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(username, key), true);
CloudQueueClient clnt = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

string logQueueReference = "log2";
CloudQueue queue = clnt.GetQueueReference(logQueueReference);

queue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

The following request is generated:

```
HEAD /log2?comp=metadata&timeout=90 HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2012-02-12
User-Agent: WA-Storage/2.0.6.0
x-ms-date: Tue, 29 Apr 2014 13:26:29 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey username:transformedkey
Host: username.queue.core.windows.net
```

And the following response is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 0cc84a81-73e1-4a8c-bf16-098af2b21149
Date: Tue, 29 Apr 2014 15:26:29 GMT
```

I've double-double-double checked the credentials. They are copy-pasted from the dialog at manage.windowsazure.com. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While most common cause for this 403 error is incorrect account key (so I would request you to check it again) however this error may also come if the clock on your computer is off (also known as `clock skewness`). Please check the clock on your computer and ensure that it is not off way too much. See this thread for more details: [403 error in production from WindowsAzure.Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828279/403-error-in-production-from-windowsazure-storage).

Comment: You got it! My clock was off. I did not expect that in this modern age. Ah well.

Comment: hi Mantri, what do you really mean "clock on your computer is off" ？ I change my time zone to central US, still not work. can you please tell me what is it?