# "Authentication failed" when using the Azure Storage SDK for Android with a know working account key

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Using the Azure Storage SDK for Android at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android, I get an Authentication Failed exception when running a query (or any other operation).

The full exception message is "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

I have tried creating the account both using the connection string and also by passing in the credentials (account name and Base64 encoded key) manually.

```
    fun getCustomers(): List<CustomerEntity> {
        //val account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString)

        val creds = StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("[accountName]", "[storageKey]")
        val account = CloudStorageAccount(creds, true, "core.windows.net")

        val client = account.createCloudTableClient()
        val table = client.getTableReference("Customers")
        table.createIfNotExists();
        
        val query = TableQuery.from(CustomerEntity::class.java)

        val res = table.execute(query)
        return res.toList()
    }
```

The connection string is exactly the same (copied and pasted) from a working C# application that uses the same account.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it would auth with C# but not with Android.

Comment: One possible reason I can think of for this error is date/time mismatch. Can you check the date/time on the machine (or emulator) where you are running the code to see if it is set incorrectly?

Comment: I just checked the time on the emulator and it was correct. However, I ran the application again in the emulator and lo and behold it worked.
I can only guess that the act of opening the time settings forced a time sync or something and corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: Fantastic. Next time that happens, please do check the time in the emulator. Please check these for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368984/windows-azure-queue-returns-403-forbidden/23369575#23369575 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828279/403-error-in-production-from-windowsazure-storage.