# Image resizer with azure blob storage. Returns "403 forbidden" when going through the resizer

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer

We have been using image resizer with azurereader2 for quite a while with no problem. After a small release (that really shouldnt have anything to do with this) we suddenly get errors when we try to access the images through the resizer.

This is only a problem on our test environment, the new release and image resizer etc. works just fine in production.
Both production and test is hosted in azure, and both use their own azure blob storage.

example url:
test.mysite.com/images/pim/b6ffa894-bc8f-4f1b-a1e8-ef115b78a56f.jpg?width=250&height=312&format=jpg&scale=both&mode=pad

returns the following error

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.c__DisplayClass13.b__12(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobClient.cs:line 788
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 299
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.EndGetBlobReferenceFromServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobClient.cs:line 630
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.c__DisplayClass1`1.b__0(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 66
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureReader2Plugin.d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ImageResizer.Util.AsyncUtils.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at ImageResizer.Storage.Blob.Open() in C:\projects\resizer\Plugins\ImageResizer.Storage\Blob.cs:line 41
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.GetStreamFromSource(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean& disposeStream, String& path, Boolean& restoreStreamPosition)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.LoadImage(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean restoreStreamPos)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource, Boolean addFileExtension)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1(Stream stream)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.c__DisplayClass28_0.b__0()
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.LockProvider.TryExecute(String key, Int32 timeoutMs, LockCallback success)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.GetCachedFile(String keyBasis, String extension, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean asynchronous)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context, IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, HttpModuleRequestAssistant ra, IVirtualFile vf)
   at XXX.Web.Modules.CustomImageResizingInterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, HttpModuleRequestAssistant ra, IVirtualFile vf) in E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\4773e55a378b97a1\src\Portal\Portal\Infrastructure\Web\Modules\CustomImageResizingInterceptModule.cs:line 15
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Request Information
RequestID:e8c13071-0001-00c2-437e-d8b9c7000000
RequestDate:Mon, 29 May 2017 13:19:16 GMT
StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

the url
test.mysite.com/images/pim/b6ffa894-bc8f-4f1b-a1e8-ef115b78a56f.jpg  correctly redirects to the image in the azure blob.

I have tried regenerating the access key for the blob storage, without any luck.
I have tried pointing to another blob storage from our test env, that does not work either.

I can access the test blob storage just fine from my local environment.

/resizer.debug reports 0 issues detected.

Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know if i can provide additional info.

Comment: Are you sure that your test environment isn't overriding your azure access credentials somehow? ImageResizer doesn't have any code that would behave differently in test vs. production, or cause Azure to return 403.

Comment: Also, check your system clock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828279/403-error-in-production-from-windowsazure-storage

Comment: I tried making a new connection using the connection string in my web.config, and just using it to get a img and show it on the frontpage. like so

https://gist.github.com/Skaanning/5cddf95a0d1ff210482d99a683e0be9c.

This works without issue. Shouldnt that cover both the system clock case as well as the faulty azure access credentials?

Comment: i updated the gist above. It looks like image resizer is not involved in this. 
I can access the images with GetBlobReference() but using GetBlobReferenceFromServer() as well as its async version will throw the 403

Comment: 403 exception indicates authenticationth is not correct.`GetBlobReference()` that has no  interact with azure storge. but `GetBlobReferenceFromServer()` does.  According to your description that it works correctly on the local enviroment. It seems that you set the connection string in the Azure portal appsetting. If it is that case, please have a try to add or update the connection string via azure portal webapp test environment [appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure).

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT Yeah, i think its safe to say that image resizer is innocent in this. 
I have tried generating a new connection string and using that, but it didnt work. Ive created a new question, i should probably close this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393468/azure-blob-returns-403-forbidden-with-correct-access-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely a azure blob storage connection problem, image resizer is not the culprit.