# Azure Queue Rest API "Resource Not Found 404"

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

On an Angular app I am trying to peek at a message in a queue (with multiple messages on it) on Azure using this URL format: `https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages?peekonly=true` from [Peek Messages | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/peek-messages).

My request: (_http is a variable name for HttpClient)

```
return this._http.get('https://***.queue.core.windows.net/***/messages?peekonly=true')
```

It returns`status: 404, statusText: "The specified resource does not exist."` I have triple checked my request URL and confirmed that CORS is enabled. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Storage returns 404 Not Found because Storage service is private by default. Plain URL without authorization can't access private resource.

I recommend you to use [Shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fqueues%2ftoc.json#what-is-a-shared-access-signature) to authorize your request.

Go to Storage account on portal, click Shared access signature blade to generate sas token. Peek message needs (Queue/Object/Read) as the minimal permission. See [permission by operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas#queue-service).

[image]

Then append generated SAS token to your url, note that you need to replace `?` with `&` as it's the second query parameter in url.

Comment: Thanks very much @JerryLiu. I went through that process, enabled all permissions, and appended the sas token to the end of the url with `&`. I got a `403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)`. I then tried some other basic requests from the documentation and got the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @kg123 Have you tried the url with sas directly in browser? Two potential causes 1.the token may have expired. 2. url encoding issue in code

Comment: I have tried it in the browser and it have me the same error. I tried a new key to confirm expiration wasn't the issue. Also, I already have successful calls in my code  for a blob in the same storage account as the queue I'm trying to access. So, I dont think the encoding would be an issue.

Comment: forgot to mention @JerryLiu

Comment: @kg123 Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828279/403-error-in-production-from-windowsazure-storage/22829215#22829215).

Comment: Aligned my computer timezone with the server and storage account timezone, as well as the timezone option in creating a SAS token. Getting the same error. Opened a support request with Azure. I'll post what I find out @JerryLiu

Comment: The solution was putting the SAS token before the message operation options like `https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages?SASTOKEN&peekonly=true`. @JerryLiu

Comment: @kg123 Good to know you conquered it, a little strange that I don't need to put the token at the first parameter to access.